# Можно ли убрать контур кнопок в tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Хотелось бы иметь виджет Button без этих краев.Это может понадобится, когда хочется передать параметр command к простому тексту(но Label к сожалению, этого не позволяет).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю немного о чём вы но... А почему не с Label?

```
label.bind("<Button-1>", on_click_function)
```